# Importing bcp output, barfing on datetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've been beating my head against this for a while, so I'm finally asking for some suggestions.  We have a very unfortunately designed table that doesn't perform well, and it's been out there long enough that was have many customers who've put around 50M rows each into it.

I've been experimenting with ways of fixing the table design, but obviously, the biggest constraint is how to migrate the data efficiently.  Dropping primary keys and having the table reshuffle blows out the disk space on the transaction log.  Creating a new table and doing INSERT new SELECT * OLD likewise.

I started experimenting with **bcp**, and trying to follow recommendations I found here (this was linked from an Oflow article - http://www.sommarskog.se/bulkload.html) but so far I'm stymied by a problem on the import.  It always fails on the first row, trying to process the **datetime** column.  Nothing I've found in any Oflow article seems to address the problem.

I did the bcp export with -N to get all native mode, created a format file with -N.  The new table I tried to import into was just different in the primary keys and indexes, not the column layout; that didn't work.  I tried creating an empty table of the same structure; that didn't work.  I tried all 3 import methods described in the above article; none of them got past the datetime import issue.

I'm hoping someone can direct me how to get past the datetime import issue.

The table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [Notes](
[NoteID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ObjectTypeID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[ObjectID] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
[CreationTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[NoteTypeID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[AuthorUserID] [int] NOT NULL,
[AuthorName] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[AuthorEmail] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Message] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[ObjectSubTypeID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[IpAddr] [nvarchar](48) NULL,
[Source] [tinyint] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_RC_Note] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ObjectTypeID] ASC,
[ObjectID] ASC,
[CreationTime] DESC,
[NoteID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

The export method:

```
bcp NotesTest.Notes out .\Notes2.bcp -c -N -U foo -P bar -S dbserver
bcp NotesTest.Notes format nul -T  -f Notes.fmt -N -U foo -P bar -S dbserver
```

The import methods tried:

```
bcp NotesTest.Notes in .\Notes2.bcp -U foo -P bar -S dbserver -h TABLOCK -b 50000 -f Notes.fmt

BULK INSERT Notes
FROM '\\myserver\myshare\notes2.bcp'
WITH (
     BATCHSIZE      = 50000
    ,CODEPAGE       = 'RAW'
    ,DATAFILETYPE   = 'native'
    ,FIRSTROW       = 1
    ,FORMATFILE     = '\\myserver\myshare\Notes.fmt'
    ,MAXERRORS      = 20
    ,TABLOCK
    );

SET IDENTITY_INSERT RC.RC_Note ON
INSERT INTO RC.RC_Note (NoteID, ObjectTypeID, ObjectID, CreationTime, NOteTypeID,AuthorUserID,AUthorName, AuthorEmail,Message,ObjectSubTypeID,IpAddr,Source) 
    SELECT NoteID, ObjectTypeID, ObjectID, CreationTime, NOteTypeID,AuthorUserID,AUthorName, AuthorEmail,Message,ObjectSubTypeID,IpAddr,Source
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '\\myserver\myshare\notes2.bcp',
    FORMATFILE='\\myserver\myshare\Notes.fmt'
) AS t1;
```

The error message received on all the imports (with a little different dressing around it, depending on the method):

```
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 4 (CreationTime).
```

Thanks

Comment: As an aside, what does "doesn't perform well" specifically look like?  Queries, updates, etc?  Perhaps you could look instead at other indexing strategies and maybe partitioning?

Comment: What does the actual CreationTime in the file look like?

Comment: Based on the error, it is as if it is trying to put a large value into a smaller column, which requires me to ask: Are the two table formats exactly the same? I'm wagering that the exported column is, perhaps, varchar/Nvarchar (a text datetime field) instead of actual datetime.  To test, create the destination table by using `SELECT * INTO new FROM old WHERE 1=0`, which will create an empty table, then try the BCP again.

Comment: As to "doesn't perform well", there are a few things.  First, it's a growth nightmare - all the inserts go in based on those type ids (rather than the identity column) so it's block split city all the time.  Second, there aren't enough indexes for the range of queries run on it and the primary key requires you to do a bunch of separate queries by type and UNION ALL them when you want to, say, search by date range to get any kind of performance.  The redesign was to make the identity column the primary key and add the indexes to support more types of queries.

Comment: Yeah, the error message says one thing, but the export was datetime, the column being imported into is datetime.  No clarity on what could be "truncating."  The export with -N produces a raw binary file, so what it looks like in the file is not an ISO 8601 string, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears to be a silent but deadly conflict of export options.  I noticed when going back to review the link in Vergil's answer that I'd accidentally left **-c** in the export line when I switched to native mode.  Bcp didn't complain, but the output file it produced doesn't appear to be valid.

```
bcp NotesTest.Notes out .\Notes2.bcp -c -N -U foo -P bar -S dbserver
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check out [this description of native format import options.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-native-format-to-import-or-export-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#command_options)

Datafiletype for a native BCP import should be 'Native', and no format file should be used If the tables are identical. Here are two specific command line options:

```
Command      Option                  Description
bcp            -n                    Causes the bcp utility to use the native data types of the data.
BULK INSERT  DATAFILETYPE ='native'  Uses the native or wide native data types of the data. Note that DATAFILETYPE is not needed if a format file specifies the data types.
```

Try the default native file imports, and see if they work for you.